# ruby exec powershell windows

Tags: ruby, powershell, cmd, 32bit-64bit

When I run the following in ruby:

```
`powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command get-module -listavailable`
```

...the result I get is different from if I just run cmd and execute:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command get-module -listavailable
```

How can I fix this, so I can yield the same result?

Comment: I suspect that they are running in different user contexts and thus would potentially be loading different modules.

Comment: so apparently it is enumerating C:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\modules

Comment: It should be enumerating modules under your user profile (typically under C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The fix apparently is the sysnative alias. Use:

C:/windows/sysnative/windowspowshell/v1.0/powershell.exe

Instead of syswow64 or system32 or none.

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx